# Selenium Webdriver Drag And Drop doesn't work on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, intellij-idea

I have automated test (Selenium Webdriver, Java), which should drag and drop elements.
I use the following code:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragable)
              .moveToElement(dropable)
              .release(dragable).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Also i used:

```
Action dd = builder.dragAndDrop().build();
```

When i use it from IDE(IntelliJ IDEA) it works!
When i use it from Jenkins( Jenkins runs from Commond Line) it works!
But when i run this test from Jenkins(Jenkins runs as Windows Services) it doesn't work. It's just nothing happens.

Help me please!

Comment: what do you mean by `"When i use it from Jenkins( Jenkins runs from Commond Line) it works"` also, how do you execute your test from jenkins, what command you use?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I mean when i execute my Jenkins Job (when Jenkins runs from commond line, "java -jar jenkins.war") dragAndDrop is works.But when I execute my Jenkins Job(when Jenkins runs as Windows Services) dragAndDrop doesn't work(i mean there are no errors in console log, and in browser dragAndDrop didn't performed)